# Makefile conditional error

Tags: makefile, conditional-statements, gnu-make

I am attempting to do a make statement to check the architecture. I am very close to getting it to work:

```
test:
        ifeq ("$(shell arch)", "armv7l")
                echo "This is an arm system"
        else
                echo "This is not an arm system."
        endif
```

I have one issue: although this seems to resolve to `ifeq ("i386", "armv7l")` which should be false, I get the following error:

```
$ make
ifeq ("i386", "armv7l")
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `"i386",'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `ifeq ("i386", "armv7l")'
make: *** [test] Error 2
```

So, it is resolving to two strings comparing to each other, but there is a syntax error. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot use make statements like `ifeq` inside a recipe.  Recipes (the lines that begin with TAB) are passed to the shell.  The shell doesn't understand `ifeq`; that's a make construct.

You'll have to use shell if-statements inside a recipe.  And, you don't have to use `$(shell ...)` in a recipe, because you're *already* in a shell.

```
test:
        if [ `arch` = armv7l ]; then \
            echo "This is an arm system"; \
        else \
            echo "This is not an arm system."; \
        fi
```

This is likely not the best way to handle this, but since you didn't provide any info on what you're really trying to do with this it's all we can say.

Comment: How much clearer can it be? I'm just trying to check the architecture and conditionally do statements. But thank you for the answer. Accepted.

Comment: If you really only wanted to write an if-statement in every single recipe line then I agree it's clear.  Most of the time, though, people _really_ want to do something more than that, like use different compiler flags or different compilers, add different source files, etc.  There are much more elegant ways to do these kinds of things than adding lots of if-statements throughout all your makefile recipes.

Comment: By the way `==` is synonymous with `=`

Comment: Thanks for the fixup with `endif` vs. `fi`: that was a dumb mistake.  However, using `==` instead of `=` is not correct.  The shell's test facility uses the single-= operator to compare strings.  Bash has an extension, which is not portable, that allows it to also recognize `==` for string comparison.  Since make _always_ run `/bin/sh`, regardless of the user's shell, this will fail on any system where `/bin/sh` is not actually bash and adheres to the standard in this respect.

Answer (score 21):

As MadScientist said, `make` is passing the `ifeq` lines to the shell, but if you write it properly, you can definitely mix make constructs like `ifeq` with commands within a recipe. You just need to understand how `make` parses a `Makefile`:

If a line begins with a `TAB`, it is considered a command for the shell **regardless of where the line is within the file**.

If it doesn't begin with a `TAB`, `make` interprets it as part of its own language.

So, to fix your file, just avoid starting the `make` conditionals with a `TAB`:

```
test:
ifeq ("$(shell arch)", "armv7l")
        echo "This is an arm system"
else
        echo "This is not an arm system."
endif
```

Comment: Both answers are great. Thanks for explaining why it would not work. I will definately keep this in mind!